# Custom power source switching

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, switching-losses

I designed a circuit to switch between battery (+ up converter) and 5 V coming from a cable based on an n-channel and p-channel MOSFET.

[image: simulation]

Will this work? Will the voltage drop be minor? Under a load, Falstad shows 4.4 V. It's too low; what is causing it?

---

So based on answers and my own research - I did this, based on p-channel MOSFETs only. I wonder if this will work?

[image: please ignore the leds and solder bridges]

(Please ignore the LEDs and solder bridges.)

Comment: Can you describe in a little more detail how you expect your circuit to behave? Like under what conditions you expect the MOSFETs to be switched on or off? [Edit] your question to add more detail - don't add it as comments.

Comment: Did you mean not to connect +5V to the gates? As shown, both are tied G-S so it's just a back-to-back diode.

Comment: Yes, the N-channel MOSFET is just acting as its body diode here. To turn the MOSFET on, the voltage on the gate wold have to be *higher* than the voltage on the source. A common newbie mistake is thinking that any positive voltage on the gate means a transistor is turned on, when actually, it has to be a voltage higher than the source.

Comment: How I imagine it to work: if any of those 5V sources are disconnected, the second one will be used. but if both are connected, the one above will be used and the one below will be blocked.

@user253751 oh... Any idea how i get a higher voltage to drive the gate?

Comment: @Szybet you could use the 5V to power a charge pump, for example. You could also use a P-channel MOSFET that turns on at 0 volts (hence -5V Vgs, enough to turn it on), and some circuit to create a 0 volt signal when the 5V is present and a 5V signal when only the other one is present.

Comment: @Szybet - You posted an "answer", but it was still asking for advice. Therefore it was still a question and should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box. It has been moved into the question as an edit i.e. as an update instead. *Unless* you are writing the *final conclusion* to your own question, without using any other answers (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should edit the question to add new information or updates etc. See the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: Your second circuit has the PMOS devices connected so their body diodes conduct 5VB or 5VC to 5VM. It might work if you reverse then drain for source.